# Google+ Like Picture Gallery

Tags: jquery, gallery, google-plus

I am looking for help in recreating this type of gallery: https://plus.google.com/photos/104987932455782713675/albums/posts

The mosaic effect (perhaps a library)
The hover image-expansion effect
The infinite scrolling

Can you point me to libraries or perhaps tutorials. I imagine most of that stuff can be achieved with jQuery.

Thanks!

Comment: I am curious to know as well, if there is something already created, but I couldn't find it. The best thing that I found is this http://www.techbits.de/2011/10/25/building-a-google-plus-inspired-image-gallery/